# Error during Adding Class Library in My Project

Tags: c#

I had created one Class library as BLL.Inside that one Class as ClsEmployeeMaster.
I want to use this library in my projet of Visitor Management.
when i was trying to add this as reff. then it added successfully but when I was start to Build then errors occurs as :

> Error 5   The type or namespace name 'ClsEmployeeMaster' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   so What to do??

Comment: are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? use using

Comment: maybe you neet to put `using BLL.Inside` in your cs file

Comment: I had used using BLL.But Problem occured when i was build my project.

Comment: If both projects are in the same solution, make sure that the BLL project compiled successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to add a reference to your BLL. If you want to use the classes defined in your BLL you need to name them with the full namespace. Something like

```
MyCompany.MyBLL.ClsEmployeeMaster em = new MyCompany.MyBLL.ClsEmployeeMaster();
```

or you can simplify your typing with

```
using MyCompany.MyBLL;

....

ClsEmployeeMaster em = new ClsEmployeeMaster();
```

Comment: using BLL; BLL.ClsEmployeeMaster objEmpMaster = new BLL.ClsEmployeeMaster();

Comment: I am supposing that you have two projects in your solution. The first project (A) needs to use a PUBLIC class in the second project (B). In this scenario you need to add a reference in A to project B (right click on References and the Add Reference, Select B from Solution group). After this you can insert the using directive. (Of course the using directive should reflect exactly the namespace in which is defined the class ClsEmployeeMaster)

Answer (score 0):

Open the class file that you have created.
Check the namespace written above the class.
for example

```
namespace MyCompany
{
    class BLL
    {
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

then add that namespace to your current .cs

```
using dllName.MyCompany;
```